# How to integrate Admob ads into ios7 app when iAds fail to fill?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, admob, iad

I want to be able to display AdMob ads in my app whenever the iAds fail to load, so any help is appreciated. This is a copy of my iAds code currently in my game.m(and view controller.m)

```
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my codes:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self addAdMob];
}

- (void) addAdMob {
    GADBannerView *adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50)];
    adBanner.rootViewController = self;
    adBanner.delegate = self;
    adBanner.adUnitID = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    adBanner.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:adBanner];
    [adBanner loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```